# Filter list of people by first letter of first name in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to filter a list of people by the starting letter of their first name in an AngularJS repeater.

The repeater is as follows:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy: 'firstname' | firstLetter:'firstname':'A'">
    <a ui-sref="people.details({ personId: {{person.id}} })">
        <span class="list__icon"><img src="img/avatar.png"></span>
        <span class="list__text">
            <span class="list__text__name">{{person.firstname}} <b>{{person.lastname}}</b></span>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

So I order it by first name and then use a custom filter called `firstLetter`:

```
.filter('firstLetter', function () {
    return function (input, letter) {
        input = input || [];
        var out = [];
        input.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item.charAt(0).toLowerCase() == letter) {
                out.push(item);
            }
        });
        return out;
    }
});
```

However I get an error that `charAt` isn't a function... Am I passing the parameters to the filter incorrectly?

Comment: Create jsfiddle or plunkr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `firstLetter` filter is missing an additional param. The first param `input` refers to the array which is being repeated through (in this case, people). The second param, `letter` should actually be the third param of your filter declaration.

```
.filter('firstLetter', function () {
    return function (input, key, letter) {
        input = input || [];
        var out = [];
        input.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log('item: ', item[key][0].toLowerCase());
            console.log('letter: ', letter);
            if (item[key][0].toLowerCase() == letter.toLowerCase()) {
                out.push(item);
            }
        });
        return out;
    }
});;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are passing parameters to filter incorrectly. By default filter input i.e your array will get passed as a first parameter.

```
.filter('firstLetter', function () {
    return function (objects, input, letter) {
        var out = [];
        angular.forEach(objects,object){
            var item = object[input];
            if (item.charAt(0).toLowerCase() == letter.toLowerCase()) {
                out.push(object);
            }
        });
        return out;
    }
});
```